# c++ placement new

Tags: c++, new

Не судите строго, это мой второй вопрос, я новичок в с++ и меня очень заинтересовал placement new, хотелось бы узнать как он работает(знаю, что он размещает объект по указанному адресу), но интересуют некоторые уточнения.

1. Если у меня есть адрес на свободный блок длиной 30 байт(за этим фрагментом идет уже аллоцированный фрагмент, где расположен сконструированный объект)
   Что будет, если я попробую расположить по этому адресу объект весом 40 байт?(terminate, затирания 10 байт сконструированного объекта, выбор ближайшего подходящего блока)?

   ```
    int main()
    {
      int * temp = new int[10]; // представим, что сразу после 10 int идет фрагмент памяти, который уже занят неким объектом
      int * temp1 = new(temp) int[100];//?
    }
   ```

2)вызовется ли деструктор для объекта, который размещается на данном участке?

Comment: 1) неопределенное поведение 2) деструкторы объектов, созданных при помощи `new`, никогда сами по себе не вызываются

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Будет неопределённое поведение.
2. У вас же в примере массив, у него деструктора нет. А если вы хотите вызвать для какого-то объекта деструктор, то надо `delete` использовать

Comment: Код относится к первой ситуации, давайте предположим, что там объект и на адрес его начала буду размещать другие данные, будет ли корректно вызван деструктор.

Comment: @Максим если вы выделили память корректно, то далее при вызове вручную `delete` деструктор корректно вызовется. Автоматически не будет вызываться